# How do I look at tags with an "Or" search?

Tags: support, tags, search

So I like perusing the questions on StackOverflow. I am a C#/C/C++ programmer, so I typically brows a tab of each at once.

It'd be nice if I could look at questions with an "or" on the tags.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20c

Will show questions tagged with both C++ and C, but I'd really like just pull all of em up at once. Can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can, by inserting "or"'s into your search like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2b%2b%20or%20c%23